# Как сделать чтобы когда у кого-то была определенная роль и когда он просит через команду другую роль прошлая роль у него снималась на Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, бот, discord.py

Например, человек получил роль через команду !role1 и он пишет команду !role2, и как сделать чтобы role1 у него снималась, а role2 присваивалась и писалось "Вам выдана роль 2, убраны роли: 1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.command()
async def role1(ctx):
    role1 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=role_id1)
    role2 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=role_id2)
    if role2 in ctx.author.roles:
        await ctx.author.remove_roles(role2)
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} У вас удалена роль {role2.name}")
    await ctx.author.add_roles(role1)
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Вам выдана роль {role1.name}")

@bot.command()
async def role2(ctx):
    role1 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=role_id1)
    role2 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=role_id2)
    if role1 in ctx.author.roles:
        await ctx.author.remove_roles(role1)
        await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} У вас удалена роль {role1.name}")
    await ctx.author.add_roles(role2)
    await ctx.send(f"{ctx.author.mention} Вам выдана роль {role2.name}")
```